# Query everything that comes after the '@'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am setting up a new query but unfortunately I got stuck in some kind of functions in SQL. I have some records with specific emails. All I want is bringing everything that comes after the '@'.

For example:

`cesarcastillo88@hotmail.com` ==> as a result I should get the following: `hotmail.com`.

This was not complicated at all because of the fact that the record shows one email only.

But...what if that record includes the following emails:

```
cesarcastillo88@hotmail.com ; laura23@gmail.com ; test@compliance.com
```

I did it perfectly for those cases with only 1 email in a single record

I used the following formula:

```
substring(**columnName**, charindex('@', sfe.**columnName**), len(sfe.**columnName**))
```

However, how am I suppose to do it with 3 emails in a single record?

My desired outcome is the following:

```
hotmail.com ; gmail.com ; compliance.com
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Do you have any sort of ID column that can be used to identify the unique row? Could you please provide better sample of your data?

Comment: Do you have access to `STRING_SPLIT`  (SQL Server 2016 onwards). Use that in a CTE to return the multiple email addresses and then process each one as you do for a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution based on the assumption that you have some sort of `ID` column that could help to identify each unique row:

```
;with smpl as (
    select * 
    from (values 
            (1, 'cesarcastillo88@hotmail.com ; laura23@gmail.com ; test@compliance.com'),
            (2, 'abc@cde.net'),
            (3, 'laura23@gmail.com ; test@compliance.com')) x(id, email)
), split(id, A, B) as (
select distinct id, CAST(LEFT(email, CHARINDEX(';',email+';')-1) as varchar(100)),
    CAST(STUFF(email, 1, CHARINDEX(';',email+';'), '') as varchar(100))
    from smpl
union all
select id, CAST(LEFT(B, CHARINDEX(';',B+';')-1) as varchar(100)),
    CAST(STUFF(B, 1, CHARINDEX(';',B+';'), '') as varchar(100))
from split
where B > ''
), clr as (
select ID, substring(LTRIM(RTRIM(A)), charindex('@', LTRIM(RTRIM(A))) + 1, len(LTRIM(RTRIM(A)))) cleanEmail
--into #tempTbl
from split
), ccat as (
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.ID, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ';'+ST1.cleanEmail  AS [text()]
            FROM clr ST1
            WHERE ST1.ID = ST2.ID
            ORDER BY ST1.ID
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) Emails
FROM clr ST2
)

select * from ccat
```

And here is some explanation on how this all works:

- First CTE expression splits emails into separate rows using `;` as a separator
- Second CTE is based on your function to remove the recipient from email address and only leave the domain
- The last one concatenates everything back and uses same `;` as separator. Feel free to add extra spaces around if that's your preferred output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of SQL Server, but I'll assume 2016 or newer.  They key is the STRING_SPLIT function.  To join it to your data, you'll want to use CROSS APPLY.

```
create table #a (
    id int identity(1,1),
    email varchar(max)
)

insert #a
values ('cesarcastillo88@hotmail.com ; laura23@gmail.com ; test@compliance.com')
, ('dannyboy@irish.com')


select id
, email
, substring(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) + 1, len(email)) as domain
from #a


select a.id
, substring(ltrim(rtrim(b.value)), CHARINDEX('@', ltrim(rtrim(b.value))) + 1, len(ltrim(rtrim(b.value)))) as domain
from #a a
  cross apply string_split(email, ';') b
drop table #a
```